# Sails.js - how do I change what port Socket.io is using

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I'm having a bizarre issue. I'm running Sails 0.9.7 and locally everything works great. Deployed on Heroku, everything works great except while I'm at work. At work, the pages work fine, but Sockets is getting 503ed:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://gameshowhub.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/usGTFi4hOfyza-B4LN8d' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

Everywhere else I go (geographically) the page seems to work, so I think my work network is blocking the Sockets port. Does that sound right? Where can I change the socket's port in Sails - I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sails sockets will use the default port: `sails.config.port` this will be `1337` if you didn't change it.

Heroku doesn't support websockets out of the box. You'll need to enable them via:

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
```

More info at [devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets).

If websockets will get blocked via firewall they should switch to

```
htmlfile
xhr-polling
jsonp-polling
```

you may also enable `flashsockets` in the `config/sockets.js`-file.